# Is ID.X a valid JSON key - cannot parse it with newtonsoft library

Tags: json, json.net

I am using NewtonSoft to manage a ResJson string.

I want to retrieve an item from this string:

```
{
  "ID.1": "File and Menu",
  "ID_2": "Test Scenario"
}
```

`var jtok = JObject.Parse(ResJsonText).SelectToken(pair.Key);`

retrieves only the second item.

I have the latest newtonsoft.json.dll version.

Is the ID valid?
I have tested it on jsonlint.com and it says it is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the key is valid, but you cannot use a key with a `.` in the `SelectToken` method, because the `.` has special meaning as a navigation operator to that method.  In this case `ID.1` would mean "find a property called `ID` then navigate to its child object and find a property called `1`, then get its value.  Since that arrangement does not exist in your JSON, you get a null value.

Instead, you can use square bracket syntax:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken token = obj["ID.1"];
```

If you are looping through key-value pairs on a `JObject` (which I suspect you are), then you don't need to use the keys to get the values; you already have them in the `Value` property on the pairs:

```
string json = @"{ ""ID.1"": ""File and Menu"", ""ID_2"": ""Test Scenario"" }";

var jo = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach (var pair in jo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Value));
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fpcMGk